Azure MS SQL: grant sys.* and msdb.dbo.* select permissions for Grafana monitoring
I'm trying to monitor Azure MS SQL databases using this Grafana dasboard. It executes several queries to tables whose names start with sys and msdb.dbo.
I've created a dedicated grafana user for this and tried adding the user to db.datareader permissions, as well as GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: sys TO [grafana];, and GRANT view database state TO [grafana];, but I'm still getting permission errors.
Trying to directly grant select on specific tables (e.g. GRANT SELECT ON sys.dm_exec_query_stats TO grafana;) on the master database, besides being tedious, seems to not be allowed ever for the master user, as I get SQL Error [40574] [S0001]: Permissions for system stored procedures, server scoped catalog views, and extended stored procedures cannot be changed in this version of SQL Server..
What's the right way of doing this?

If the dashboard is designed for on premise SQL Server and not advertised explicitly as compatible with Azure SQL database I imagine you will encounter numerous other problems. Are you using Azure SQL database as tagged or managed instance?

Found the solution. Azure won't let you grant permissions on the sys schema in any way, either directly or by executing GRANT VIEW SERVER/DATABASE STATE commands.
You have to add your user to one of the server built in roles. In my case
ALTER SERVER ROLE ##MS_ServerStateReader## ADD MEMBER grafana;

did the trick.

Documentation for sys.dm_exec_query_stats suggests that it requires VIEW SERVER STATE permission.
The same applies to many other system views as well.

As mentioned in my question that command is not allowed by Azure sql
